# How do I put responses in that are not answers?

Tags: discussion

I have seen people post short responses/comments to questions on here but when I thought I was doing that what I posted looked like an answer. Is there some way I can indicate that my response should not be interpreted as answer?

Thanks,
-Lars

Also what is the "Tags" for on asking a question? I assume it's for the areas that I have some expertise in but I'm not familiar with this terminology. Am I right? Sorry for asking two questions in one.

Comment: Welcome to the site @lars; you need 50 rep to add comments on other people's posts.  You can add comments on your own posts at any time.  See the [faq] and the [privileges](http://diy.stackexchange.com/privileges) page for more information.  Once you have the rep to leave comments, you'll see a link 'add comment' underneath the post.  And if you want to do a lot of reading about how these sites work, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: And tags are a way of categorizing questions; you can follow certain tags and they'll be highlighted in the question list, or you can ignore them and they'll be faded out or not shown at all (that's an option on your profile page).

Comment: If you have other questions about how the site works, visit the [meta] site via the link at the top of the page and ask other there. Questions on the main site need to follow the guidelines described in the [faq].

Answer (score 1):

As Niall C. said in his comment, you need [50 reputation points](https://diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) to be able to add comments to any post. You can always comment on your own question and answers to your own question regardless of how much reputation you have.

See the [privileges page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/privileges) for a full list of the actions you can take and at what reputation they are earned.

Tags are a way of categorising questions rather than the user. So if you were asking a question about power sockets you'd add the tag [electrical](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) for example.